# What is difference between PIL and ImageMagick bindings for python?

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I research different ways for scale images (creating thumbnails) using python. Can anybody explain me fundamental difference in result images after [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) process and after [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) process.
At first sight there is no any full-featured ImageMagick [binding for python](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python). I've seen some solutions but most of them seems to be very poor (poor functionallity or documentation, bad API). In the other hand I've read that PIL has some problems with resize GIF images. And quality of result images after PIL process is worse than similar using ImageMagick.
What do you think?

Comment: PIL is very well documented, and easy to use. ImageMagick is a headache guessing game.

Comment: @fraxel Yes, PIL documentation is very good. But I'm interesting what is the difference of the resulting images?

Comment: The fundamental difference is that… they're fundamentally different libraries, designed independently of each other for different communities over a period of many years. If you have a specific question, or even want a recommendation for a specific use case, that's one thing, but if you're just asking for a general compare-and-contrast, SO is definitely not the place for that.

Comment: @abarnert ok, in the first sentence of my question I wrote that I'm interesting the result of scale operations / creating thumbnails

Comment: @Dmitry: Are you having a specific problem? I took a 512x512 GIF, followed the PIL tutorial (`im = Image.open('foo512.gif'); im.thumbnail((200,200)); im.save('foo200.gif')`) and did the simplest equivalent with `PythonMagick` and with IM's command-line `convert`, and looked at the results side-by-side… and they all look pretty good. Do you have a source image and some code that gives you a bad result with PIL, where you think IM might do a better job?

Comment: @abarnert thank you for this research. I had the same result. But there should be some difference between using PIL and Imagemagick, and I try to find it. May be you can give an example of this difference

Comment: If you cant see a difference why do you care?

Comment: @Dmitry: There are all kinds of differences between PIL and ImageMagick. Again, do you have a problem case that you're trying to solve, or are you just trying to enumerate all possible differences between two completely different libraries so you can then guess which ones might possibly be relevant to whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: @fraxel because i'm interesting of stumbling blocks of each solution

Comment: @abarnert "enumerate all possible differences between two completely different libraries" - that's right. But differences in the real applications, for example for creating thumbnail or something like it

Comment: @abarnert Also I don't think that GIL and IM are fundamentally different libraries. In any case, the scope of usage is the same (web applications for example)

Comment: @Dmitry: Both of them can be used to create thumbnails, with only a few lines of code, which you can take directly out of the examples. Both seem to do a decent job in my test case, and you say that you can't see any difference in yours. If you don't have an actual problem you're trying to solve, just pick whichever one looks more comfortable to you. If there are any problems with whichever one you choose for your use case, you'll run into them soon, and you can come back and ask a more useful question.

Comment: @Dmitry you need a different question where you, for example, show what you obtain by using certain commands with one tool and then what you obtain using another tool. If both tools are using the same procedures (you will need to investigate this), and you want to know why of them is producing different results, or how you can obtain the same result using that other tool, then you can make a specific question regarding that. There is nothing being asked here, do a diff between both documentations and check what is different there.

Comment: I know this has already been closed, but I still wanted to add the fact that I think Wand-py is an excellent Python implementation of ImageMagick - http://docs.wand-py.org/ .  I would even go so far as to say this answers the question that says "is there a full featured Python implementation of ImageMagick"?

Answer (score 3):

I've built a thumbnail generator at work using IM. What's great about IM is the ability to handle oodles of filetypes. I had to use it to generate pdf and movie thumbnails. The downside to using IM is that I spent far more time building a popen interface with IM than I did working on the other parts of the thumbnail generator put together.

PIL could be used with something like pyffmpeg, but it doesn't look as though that combination is as fully featured as IM, which is why I didn't go with it in the past. If you can get away with PIL I would suggest PIL, but if you need to generate thumbnails for more exotic filetypes or you're not happy with the quality of PIL then IM is certainly viable.

Comment: You almost never—possibly even never—need a `popen` interface for `IM`. `PythonMagick` has more than enough functionality to generate thumbnails, and a lot more. If you need to go beyond that, you can always extend `PythonMagick` or use `ctypes` or `Cython` to hit `libMagick` directly.